# R and ggplot2 : plot with factors on both axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

My data frame looks like this :

```
data
>
          | Segment 1 | Segment 2  | Segment 3
Segment 1 | 0.6861964 | 0.16669839 | 0.14710523
Segment 2 | 0.2211293 | 0.69263231 | 0.08623838
Segment 3 | 0.2595055 | 0.05354549 | 0.68694899
```

I would like to use in both axis `Segment 1`, `Segment 2` and `Segment 3` and use the values inside the table as parameters to have points of different sizes.

What I tried for the moment is to add a column Segments to the above data frame and did a `melt()` in order to obtain the following table:

```
data_melt <- melt(data, id = "Segments")
>
  | Segments  | variable  | value
1 | Segment 1 | Segment 1 | 0.68619638
2 | Segment 2 | Segment 1 | 0.22112931
3 | Segment 3 | Segment 1 | 0.25950552
4 | Segment 1 | Segment 2 | 0.16669839
5 | Segment 2 | Segment 2 | 0.69263231
6 | Segment 3 | Segment 2 | 0.05354549
```

Then trying to plot it I am stuck and could not find a ressource solving my problem.

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = Segments, y = variable, size = value))
    geom_point()
```

It plots the axis but no point appears and I get the following message:

```
geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity
```

I would like the output to look like this:
[image]

Comment: In `aes`, `x` and `y` are set to a string variables (`x="Segment 1"`), not a numeric value.  You are attempting to plot strings as points.

Comment: How should I do it ? Generaly when I use string variable in only one axis, it doesn't complain. I though that in `data_melt` the fact that they were on the same line was enough

Comment: You have forgot a `+`. VTC as "simple typographical error".

Comment: So on the x-axis you want to plot a factor essentially.  For the y-axis, what are you trying to capture ?  If you are trying to capture the `variable` number, you will have to just have the values 1 or 2 in the variable column.

Comment: I updated my question to be clearer. What I would like is that the column value would define the size of each circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce by

```
data_melt <-  data.frame(seg=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),var=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),value=runif(6))

> ggplot(test, aes(x = Seg, y = var, size = value))
Error: No layers in plot
> geom_point()
geom_point: na.rm = FALSE 
stat_identity:  
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)
```

basically you forgot a `+`

```
 ggplot(data_melt, aes(x = seg, y = var,size=value))+geom_point()
```

Comment: Ok... I think I am a bit ashamed of this one... 
Thank you !